# How to redirect to login if not authenticated in Vue with DRF

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm working with vue and django rest framework, and what I want to do is validate if I don't have a token in my localStorage (not login) redirect to login page.

Here my component code in my login.vue:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import swal from 'sweetalert'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        token: localStorage.getItem('user-token') || null
      }
    },
  methods: {
    login() {
      axios.post('http://localhost:8000/auth/', {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password,
      })
      .then(resp => {
        this.token = resp.data.token;
        localStorage.setItem('user-token', resp.data.token)
        this.$router.push('/atentusianos')
        })
      .catch(err => {
        localStorage.removeItem('user-token')
        swal("Credenciales Incorrectas", "", "error")
    })
  }
  }
}
</script>
```

If the authentication is correct, i get my token from my localStorage like this:

```
...
methods: {
    getAtentusianos(){
      let axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Token ' + this.token
        }
      }
      const path = 'http://localhost:8000/atentusianos/'
      axios.get(path, axiosConfig).then((response) => {
        this.atentusianos = response.data
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
},
created(){
  let token;
  this.token = TokenService.getToken()
  this.getAtentusianos()
}...
```

I need help please...

Comment: You can check `localStorage` in your root component if token exist take to `/home` or redirect to `/login` if it doesn't exist. You can use mounted life cycle for that

Comment: could you show me an example?

Comment: You can check the token before `this.getAtentusianos` and if it's empty it means you redirect it to login page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in your Vue Router beforeEach guard. This runs on every route before directing to the requested page, including on a new page load or refresh, so it's ideal for handling this type of logged in check.

```js
    router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('user-token')
        // If logged in, or going to the Login page.
        if (token || to.name === 'Login') {
          // Continue to page.
          next()
        } else {
          // Not logged in, redirect to login.
          next({name: 'Login'})
        }
      }
    });
```

*Note: this code assumes your login route name is Login, so you can update that accordingly.*

I also recommend using VueX to get and store your auth token, and your default value for the token in your store can be from local storage or a cookie. That just makes it more efficient, checking the Vuex store value instead of getting it from local storage or the cookie every time.

Vue Router navigation guards: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had to make a small modification: if (!localStorage.getItem('user-token') && to.name != 'Login') {
    next({name: 'Login'})} else{ next()} ...

Comment: Good catch, I was handling that differently in my code I pulled this from, and stripped it out. I added back a check for that. :)